# At exactly what point do Farabi and Avicenna differ on the theory of emanation?

Tags: metaphysics

I have been trying to find an answer to this question but I haven't able to locate anything. Please see if you can respond.

Comment: can you say a little about the theory of enamation, or at least provide a link to one. it should help getting a good answer.